Setting Prototype Object of a Constructor function vs Prototype Object of a Class In JS?
So, I was learning about Prototypes and OOPS concept in javascript. WHile playing around with prototypes, I came across this weird behaviour(weird because I am unaware of the concepts :) ).
The code for the same is as follows:


let o1 = {
  sayHi() {
    console.log("hi");
  },
  sayBye() {
    console.log("Bye");
  }
}

function ex() {
  this.naam = "ash";
}

ex.prototype = o1;
let o2 = new ex();

console.log(o2);

class example {
  constructor(a) {
    this.naam = a;
  }
}

example.prototype = o1;
const e = new example("ash");
console.log(e);



Output on console looked something like this:

I thought both the outputs will look the same in terms of their prototype but it turned out that directly assigning an object to prototype object of class doesn't seem to work at all.
I know that this is a bad practice and a new prototype shall be added to the prototype of the class using something like Object.setPrototypeOf(example.prototype, o1), but just for better understanding, I came up with this question. Would be really grateful if anyone could help me out.

The prototype property on a class is not writable:


class Example {}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Example, "prototype"));



Whereas it is writable in the case of a constructor function:


function Example() {}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Example, "prototype"));



This is why assigning to the prototype property works in the case of a constructor function but doesn't work with a class.
If you need to add a method on the prototype object of a class, define it inside the class:


class Example {
  sayHi() {
    console.log("hi");
  }
  sayBye() {
    console.log("Bye");
  }
}

const e = new Example();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Example.prototype));




Thanks @Yousaf for the answer, but could you please add the reason for the same i.e, why it is required for the class prototype to be non-writable. What would have happened if they are writable?

I don't know the exact reason but I think the prototype property is not writable because the class body is where you should define the prototype methods. Assigning to prototype property on a class instead of adding methods inside the class body doesn't make much sense. There could be another reason(s) for disallowing it.

I think it's because in OOP principles the class should be self contained, and it should ideally have almost nothing that can be altered from outside the class. The only exception being get and set to alter the state variables. Even that is not true OOP according to some purists.

That being said there are ways to add functions to an already defined class, for example the @decorator pattern.
